# Inconsistently receiving 500 with curl, while the same url works within the browser all the times

Tags: url, curl, https, forwarding

I am facing an issue while triggering HTTPS request from curl.
When I trigger a URL from the command line using curl, it gives (sometimes, not always) an HTTP error, either 404 or 500; the same URL works fine in the browser all the time. I am stuck, can someone guide me?

Brief log:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 43.249.75.65...
* Connected to api2.iHeart.com (43.249.75.65) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
 CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Fastly, Inc.;         CN=g.ssl.fastly.net
*    start date: 2016-01-12 22:28:18 GMT
*    expire date: 2017-01-12 22:28:18 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api2.iHeart.com matched
*    issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=GlobalSign Organienter code     herezation Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
*    SSL certificate verify ok.

> GET /api/v1/catalog/searchAll?apikey=YW5kcm9pZHwzfGpzb258NC4wMg%3D%3D&host=console&keywords=q&queryArtist=True&queryBundle=True&queryStation=True&queryTrack=True&queryFeaturedStation=True&queryTalkShow=true&maxRows=5 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: api2.iHeart.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 500 Domain Not Found
* Server Varnish is not blacklisted
< Server: Varnish
< Retry-After: 0
< content-type: text/html
< Cache-Control: private, no-cache
< connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 209
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Date: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 12:54:56 GMT
< Via: 1.1 varnish
< Connection: keep-alive


<html>
<head>
<title>Fastly error </title>
```

The same URL works fine in browser.

Comment: How exactly did you run your curl command? Running it like `curl 'https://api2.iHeart.com/api/v1/catalog/searchAll?apikey=YW5kcm9pZHwzfGpzb258NC4wMg%3D%3D&host=console&keywords=q&queryArtist=True&queryBundle=True&queryStation=True&queryTrack=True&queryFeaturedStation=True&queryTalkShow=true&maxRows=5'` works ok

Comment: Better phrasing of the problem, removed repetitions, fixed English typos

Comment: @Jucke84 Yes , I am running in same way, Its working sometime when response is from Apache server ,Error only with varnish https request.